# GRUB is not loading - error: two disks with number 3

Tags: raid, debian-squeeze, grub

After rebooting my Debian 6.0 server I am getting these errors on load (captured it through kvm console):

```
error: found two disks with number 3
error: superfluous RAID member (2 found)
error: file not found
grub rescue>
```

So, I'm not able to load my server, but is there any possibility to recover grub? Re-installing the whole system is not acceptable in my case

Comment: You will need to provide output one by one from grub rescue prompt. First Run `ls` and provide the output

Comment: After that you need to find which partition from `ls` output contains  `/boot` directory. By doing `ls (hd0,2)/boot` on each partition, till you find one with vmlinuz in it's output

Comment: next you will have to manually boot from that partition

Comment: or use live cd for debian with grub-repair-tool in it.